# How to display Information related you a PHP session variable login

Tags: php, variables, session

I am trying to display related information to a very basic session variable.

The session variable works by asking the user for a  username and password. I am able to echo out the username and password used in the input to login.  Now I am trying to echo out the student ID number which is connected to the login details used to login. It is currently appearing blank.

This is my "checklogin" page that shows after the login sub

```
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];           
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM studentmembers WHERE username='$myusername'
and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['username']=$myusername; 
$_SESSION['password']=$mypassword; 
$_SESSION['Student_ID']=$myuserid; 

echo 'Session varable saving username'; 

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
session_register("myuserid");
header("location:studentloginsuccess.php");
 }
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**This now takes the logged in account to the success page**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?> 
<?php 
echo 'The username that is logged in is '.$_SESSION['username'];
?> 
<?php 
echo 'Your Password is  '.$_SESSION['password'];
?> 
<?php 
echo 'Your ID is  '.$_SESSION['Student_ID'];
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Do not store password in the session variable for security purpose. And you have not assign any value to `$myuserid` any where in the code.

Comment: Try `echo "Your ID is $myuserid";` and you shouldn't be storing or echoing plain text passwords. Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Comment: where you defined `$myuserid` ?

Comment: @AwladLiton OP is defining it in `$_SESSION['Student_ID']=$myuserid;`

Comment: @Fred-ii- before above line it seems that `$myuserid` variable is not defined in your code

Comment: Yeah I saw that now. The OP should be fetching instead, then pull the ID from the DB and assign that to a session variable instead. @AwladLiton

Comment: where is **$myuserid;** defined ?

Comment: Stop editing out the question text. If you want to delete the question then do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($count==1){
session_start();

//add this code
$values = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$myuserid = $values['Student_ID']; //edited this line

$_SESSION['username']=$myusername; 
$_SESSION['password']=$mypassword; 
$_SESSION['Student_ID']=$myuserid;
```

This will work for you.

Comment: This code works, thanks.

But it only shows the first number, for example if the ID number is 89 it will just show 8

any ideas?

Comment: @user3319650 check the value of `$values` by using the `print_r($values);` and let me know the output.

Comment: hmm how would I display another column such as one that contained text? the $values just shows the one number

Comment: @user3319650 let me know the output of `print_r($values);` then I can tell you properly.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 96 [Student_ID] => 96 [1] => even [username] => even [2] => 1234 [password] => 1234 [3] => [units_taken] => )

Comment: seems to find the 96 number here, maybe its something to do with the echo?

Comment: @user3319650 I have edited the code that has the comment. it will work for you.

Comment: @user3319650 My pleasure in helping you.